# Is there a bijection between $ N $ and $ N^2 $ in which $ f(a, b) < p(a, b) $

Tags: functions, polynomials, integers

I was wondering if there exists a bijection between $ N $ and $ N^2 $, $ f $, for which there existing a polynomial in $a, b$ such that for all $ a, b \in N $, $f(a, b) < p(a, b)$.

In other words, is there a bijection between $ N $ and $ N^2 $ which is bounded by a polynomial?

If yes, can you give such an example?

If no, how would you prove it?

I know the bijection $f(a, b) = 2^{a-1} (2b - 1)$ , but it's not bounded by a polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bijection provided by [Cantor's Pairing Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) is polynomially bounded.

Indeed it is a polynomial itself -- $\pi : \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ is given by

$$\pi(x,y) \triangleq \frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2} + y$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the Cantor diagonal work here?

let $s = \lfloor \frac{-1+\sqrt{8n+1}}{2} \rfloor$
and $t = n - \frac{s(s+1)}{2}$
Let $a = s-t; b = t$

Then define $f(n) = (a, b)$.

You have that $f(n) < a + b$, which seems sufficient.